# Trying to make a discord bot join on boot

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def join_on_boot():
  chan = await client.fetch_channel(*voice channel id here*)
  await chan.connect()
client.loop.run_until_complete(join_on_boot())
```

this is the piece of code i've thought could do the work, which is make my bot join a specific Voice Channel on its boot, but the following error appears:

```
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.loop.run_until_complete(join_on_boot())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 15, in join_on_boot
    chan = await client.fetch_channel(*voice channel id here*)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 1459, in fetch_channel
    data = await self.http.get_channel(channel_id)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to wait until the bot setups it's connections, websockets, etc... You can do this by adding `await client.wait_until_ready()` at the very beginning of the function.

Comment: it never seems to start now, and i dont really have that much lines of code, aside from "on_ready" funct, this one is the only other one

Comment: Can you print something after that line? You should be a bit patient, it can take a few seconds for the bot to get ready

Comment: yep, i've added one print before the line and after the line, nothing. also ive waited for about 6/7 mins and nothing

Comment: Ah yes I know what the issue is (sorry for late reply). You're using the `loop.run_until_complete` method which will block until the function finishes however the function never finishes since it's waiting for the bot to be ready but the bot is never ready because its never ran. You could use `client.loop.create_task(join_on_boot())` instead and everything will work as expected.